# is it possible to have a fat32 rootfs partition instead of ext4?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, partition, root-filesystem, fat

I've successfully installed u-boot and linux kernel on STM32F469-disco board but I still don't have a rootfs. my board has 16MB RAM and 16MB FLASH storage and 32GB SDCARD and the CPU core of it is ARM Cortex-M4 32bit processor. I want to know can I just copy my busybox rootfs to a fat32 partition and expect the linux kernel to read it?

when I try to copy it to an NTFS partition it throws this error:

[image]

```bsh
PS C:\Users\mahya> copy -r z:\home\mahyar1284\my_projects\buildroot\buildroot-2020.08\output\target\ c:\users\mahya\desktop\target
Copy-Item: The name of the file cannot be resolved by the system. : 'Z:\home\mahyar1284\my_projects\buildroot\buildroot-2020.08\output\target\linuxrc'
```

---

*UPDATE*

tried it with tar command:

```bsh
C:\Users\mahya>tar -cf -r z:\home\mahyar1284\my_projects\buildroot\buildroot-2020.08\output\target\*
tar: Couldn't open z:/home/mahyar1284/my_projects/buildroot/buildroot-2020.08/output/target/linuxrc: Invalid argument
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

Comment: FAT32 doesn't support symbolic links, and ones such as `/bin -> /usr/bin` may exist in a typical Linux root directory.

Comment: @DannyNiu what about NTFS or EXFAT? I need a format to be in common between linux and windows.

Comment: NTFS would work, as Windows used to have a subsystem for Unix, as well as currently a subsystem for Linux. ExFAT doesn't support symlink though.

Comment: @DannyNiu it throws error when trying to copy symlink files to ntfs partition. (I've updated my question). what can I do to copy my rootfs?

Comment: If you're copying using Windows GUI, then the GUI shell may throw some errors. Try command line (DOS-style, or PowerShell).

Comment: @DannyNiu I tryed it with powershell too. again, it throws the same error. (I've updated my question and pasted the powershell result)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119618/discussion-between-mahyar-shokraeian-and-dannyniu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you can't use NTFS or FAT32/exFAT to host the root filesystem:

- FAT32/ExFAT do not support permissions or symbolic/hard links
- NTFS* works via the userspace fuse daemon, so an entire filesystem will belong to a single user which is again incompatible with most Linux distros

I'm now running Fedora 33, and I have a number of files not owned by root:

```
/usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d
/etc/polkit-1/rules.d
/var/log/ntpstats
/var/log/chrony
/var/lib/geoclue
/var/lib/chrony
/var/lib/chrony/drift
/var/lib/avahi-autoipd
/var/lib/avahi-autoipd/*
/var/lib/tpm2-tss/system/keystore
/var/lib/openvpn
/var/lib/ntp
/var/lib/unbound
/var/spool/mail/*
```

***Update**: Starting with Linux 5.15, NTFS now has a proper kernel driver (module) which allows to use NTFS as a root FS.

Comment: I'm going to use busybox or buildroot for my filesystem and I don't care about the file permisions for now. I just need to boot my system. is there anyway to do it?

Comment: If you include fuse and mount.ntfs-3g in your initrd, it should probably work.

Comment: what should I do to copy my rootfs to that NTFS partition? it throws this `The name of the file cannot be resolved by the system` error

Comment: What file gives you this error?

Comment: all the symlink files to the busybox file

Comment: Try `tar -cf`'ring and un`tar -xf`ring instead.

Comment: also tryed it with tar but again it thowed error for the symlink files (the first symlink to busybox is `linuxrc` file) you can see the error in my updated question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119620/discussion-between-mahyar-shokraeian-and-artem-s-tashkinov).

Comment: **Would be nice if people downvoting the answer at least left comments why they do that**.